# Можно так сказать?

Tags: лексика

"Медленно тающие ледники" или здесь допущена ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу ошибки. А в чем сомнения?
Если вы о возможности слитного написания, то оно определяется наличием термина "медленнотающий", я допускаю его существование, но о нем ли идёт речь и вообще о применимости этого термина может судить только специалист, да и то - только по контексту.

Answer (score 1):

***Абляция*** в гляциологии — **уменьшение массы ледника** или снежного покрова **в результате таяния**, испарения или отделении айсбергов (у покровных ледников), зависящее главным образом от климатических факторов.
Ледник тает медленно - низкая абляция, ледник тает быстро - высокая.

***У медленно тающих ледничков*** скоро начнут оживать и цвести растения.
[**Тотальный диктант, Таймырское озеро**](https://totaldict.ru/dictants/taymyrskoe-ozero/)

*...сохранить максимум ценной информации касательно **медленно тающих горных ледников.***
[**Глобальное потепление**](http://www.popmech.ru/science/252482-globalnoe-poteplenie-zachem-uchenye-privozyat-v-antarktidu-led/)

*Еще один **стремительно тающий ледник,** считающийся самым красивым в Северной Америке, за последние годы потерял почти половину своего объема.*
[**Ледники**](http://www.wonderfulnature.ru/statji/lednik.php)

Предложение верное - и с научной, и с лексической точки зрения.